# PayPal PHP SDK "Invalid Fields passed in plan. Pass only a valid plan-id." with brand new plan

Tags: php, paypal, sdk

I've searched and searched and have had no luck. Trying to use the PayPal PHP SDK to create a recurring payment, and from what I've understood, you need to create a billing plan for this to happen. I've tried following their sample files for such thing (located [here](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/blob/master/sample/billing/CreateBillingAgreementWithPayPal.php)) and I keep ended up at the same error. At this point, I've nearly entirely copy/pasted the examples. Everything I've read leads me to what I already had.

Here's my code: https://gist.github.com/Danktuary/10f5b70e7f0c7ca075fc7be7bc89a802

I'm using Laravel for this, but that shouldn't matter much. My `App\Billing\PayPal` class has an `apiContext()` method that returns the proper API context needed. The perpetrating lines are lines 116-120, i.e.:

```
$createdPlan = $this->updatePlan();

$plan = new Plan();
$plan->setId($createdPlan->getId());
$agreement->setPlan($plan);
```

Everything I've read tells me do it like that. When I use Laravel's `dd()` function to see if the `$plan` variable has the correct contents, it does show a proper PayPal plan ID. When I `dd()` the `$createdPlan` variable, it does show a proper Plan object. I'm honestly not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Apologies for the mixed code style and large file; I haven't gotten around to cleaning this up after copying & pasting their sample code, since I just wanted a working version of it first.

EDIT: Ahh, nevermind... It was my own fault. Ended up calling `$agreement->create()` twice.  Sorry 'bout that.